# 'Found a circular dependency when saving.' when trying to save a pointer to existing Parse Object

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfobject

I have a `Post` and a `Comment` class. I'm trying to save a comment, with pointer to the post object. I've got my post object's ID. Here is my code:

```
PFObject *comment = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Comment"];
comment[@"content"] = comment;
PFObject *post = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"Post" objectId:postId];
comment[@"post"] = post;
[comment saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if(succeeded){
        //rest...
    }
}];
```

However, saving it immediately raises exception: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Found a circular dependency when saving.'` at the client side.

I've also tried `PFObject *post = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithObjectId:postId` too, which results in `'+[PFObject parseClassName]: unrecognized selector sent to class` error.

Post doesn't depend on a comment object in any way, (and even if it did, it's already a saved object (as the user is commenting on it) and a pointer should't cause it) why am I getting this error?

Comment: Have you tried using the actual, saved post object rather than the objectWithoutData?

Comment: @danh I don't have access to it. I just have the ID of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Parse often and I'm not sure why it is saying you have a circular dependency. It looks to me that your problem is these lines:

```
PFObject *comment = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Comment"];
comment[@"content"] = comment;
```

You are loading an object, then setting that object as the "content." Each time you load the comment object, you are saving the comment object within the parent object, creating a loop. Could you try rewriting this, and maybe make a new class that manages both posts and comments?

Comment: You're right. It was a typo (actually forgot to rename a variable). I had "comment" as content string, then I've renamed it, forgetting to rename that line. My bad.

Comment: I can't believe I made the same mistake. Thanks.